# How to solve this differential equation? Related to kinetic modeling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation of the form

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = k^ez(t)-k^ty(t) $$

I know the solution from a textbook, but I'm unable to find how to solve it and it's really bugging me. For anyone who's interested it pertains to kinetic modeling. I do not believe there's a closed form solution, but I'm interested in a solution of the form y(t) = .... The solution I've seen from the textbook involves an integral on the right hand side. The boundary conditions are y(0) = z(0) = 0

Comment: There is no equation for $z$. Is it arbitrary given function?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. Yes z is a given (measured) function

Answer (score 2):

First rearrange your equation like this
$$
dy/dt+k^{t}y=k^{e}z(t)
$$
Then find an integrating factor like this
$$
e^{{\int k^{t} dt}} =  e^{{\int e^{t*ln(k)} dt}} = e^{k^{t}/ln(k)}
$$
Multiply equation by integrating factor
$$
e^{k^{t}/ln(k)}dy/dx+e^{k^{t}/ln(k)}k^{t}y = e^{k^{t}/ln(k)}k^{e} z(t)
$$
$$
d/dt[ye^{k^{t}/ln(k)}] = e^{k^{t}/ln(k)}k^{e} z(t)
$$
Integrate both sides
$$
ye^{k^{t}/ln(k)} = \int e^{k^{t}/ln(k)}k^{e} z(t)dt
$$
Finally divide the exponential on the left hand side
$$
y = e^{-k^{t}/ln(k)}\int e^{k^{t}/ln(k)}k^{e} z(t)dt
$$